# Xamarin Forms - How to get files from custom folder on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I've figured all this out for IOS but I need to do the same for Android.

On my Android device, I've created a new folder "MyFolder" and saved some images to it.

I now need to get those images into a list.

This is what I have so far, but the images list always has count=0

```
 var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

 // path result is:  "/data/user/0/com.raj.myfolder/files"

 List<string> images = new List<string>();
 foreach (var image in Directory.GetFiles(path))
 {
     images.Add(image);
 }
```

Comment: where did you create "MyFolder"?  Why are you trying to load them from the "Personal" folder and not "MyFolder"?

Comment: @Jason On the phone there's a folder called 'Files' and I created my folder in there. That's part of my question, I don't know how to reference the folder by name

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: Doesn't really explain how to use the MediaStore API

Comment: You could try to take the root path of the external storage and then splice your folder name.